# Cannot mount vboxsf from /etc/rc.local

Tags: mount, virtualbox, startup

I'm mounting a sharefolder using `mount -t vboxsf` with root without problem by the command `mount -t vboxsf logs /tmp/logs/`.

I'm trying to mount this sharefolder on every reboot of the machine so I created a quick script that I'm running into `/etc/rc.local` as `/root/Scripts/boot.sh || exit 1`:

```
#!/bin/sh 
mkdir /tmp/logs
mount -t vboxsf logs /tmp/logs > /root/Scripts/bootlog 2> /root/Scripts/bootlogerror
```

Everytime when the script is running through `rc.local` I'm getting an error:

```
/sbin/mount.vboxsf : mounting failed with the error : No such device
```

but the folder `logs` get created in `/tmp`.

Any idea how I could get a workaround for this situation? Per the message error here I'm guessing that I'm mounting the share folder too early on the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue, but got it working by `cd`ing to the home folder first.

```
cd /home/username
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000 sharedfolder mountpointinhome
```

Credit to @Danibix on askubuntu https://askubuntu.com/a/861638/68837